# Não consigo centralizar texto com o "vertical-align"

Tags: css

Quero que o meu texto fique centralizado horizontalmente e verticalmente no elemento `<div>`. Para isso, estou utilizando as propriedades `text-align` e `vertical-align` para este elemento.

O problema é que a propriedade `vertical-align: middle;` não está centralizando o texto verticalmente. Abaixo está o meu código:

```css
#myDiv {
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Este daqui é o meu texto</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` funciona apenas quando o *display* for *table-cell* (ou *inline*, em alguns casos).

Comment: Uma observação é que o table-cell faz o elemento se comportar como um elemento <td>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa Jean, dá uma olhada e vê se isso atende o que você espera:

```css
 #myDiv {
            border: 2px solid #0f0;
            height: 100px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
            width: 300px;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="myDiv">Este daqui é o meu texto</div>
```